# laravel 5.5 whereIn query not working

Tags: laravel

I can do $extra then not working properly :

```
$price = DB::table('extras')->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(ex_name) as ex_name, 
SUM(ex_price) as ex_price')->whereIn('id',[$extra])->get();
```

if i use direct [7,2] then working fine :

```
$price = DB::table('extras')->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(ex_name) as ex_name, 
SUM(ex_price) as ex_price')->whereIn('id',[$extra])->get();
```

here is my query if i use variable $extra which contain value <7,2> then query not working if i use direct [7,2] then working anyone help me please thx

Comment: Why are you copying same parts of code twice? Please read through this and edit accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `$extra = [7,2]` you don't need use `[]` outside `$extra` again,
just use `$price = DB::table('extras')->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(ex_name) as ex_name, SUM(ex_price) as ex_price')->whereIn('id',$extra)->get();`

Comment: thx your reply i use this but then show error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: $extra value is 7,2

Comment: can you show me the code how you assign the value to variable? from your message, `7,2`, I don't know it's an array, or you are just assign a string to it, or something else

Comment: using ajax i pass the value extra and get in controller $extra = trim($request->extra, "'");

Comment: what's the purpose of `trim($request->extra, "'")` ? try use `$extra = explode(",", trim($request->extra));`

Comment: actually i get via ajax this array Array
(
    [action] => add
    [code] => 4
    [quantity] => 1
    [extra] => 7,2
) and i use whereIn() function in query that syntax is whereIn('id', [7,2]) if i use explode then $extra value convert in array and then not working

Comment: so you don't want $extra be an array? `[7,2]` that's an array

Comment: i want that syntax whereIn('id', [1,2,3])

Comment: that's what explode do, separate original text by comma, convert it into an array whereIn can use

Comment: sorry i cant understand